# callFunctionInBackground doesn't work properly when the Parse iOS sdk was updated to 1.14

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I updated the library from 1:12 to 1.14.2.
Now when I call a function in the Cloud Code, the fetch of the User is undefined.

The function call:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getListOfItems"
                       withParameters:nil
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {...
```

The iOS console log of user:

```
user <PFUser: 0x7bd910f0, objectId: qiW9i8rQCN, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7bc18890>";...
```

The response of Cloud code:

```
error: Error generating response. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined]
```

The log of the request:

```
{
  "params": {},
  "master": false,
  "installationId": "xxx",
  "log": {
    "appId": "xxx"
  },
  "headers": {
    "host": "xxx",
    "connection": "close",
    "user-agent": "xxx",
    "x-parse-app-display-version": "1.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "x-parse-application-id": "xxx",
    "accept-language": "en-us",
    "x-parse-client-key": "xxx",
    "x-parse-os-version": "10.0 (15G31)",
    "x-parse-app-build-version": "1",
    "x-parse-client-version": "i1.14.2",
    "x-parse-installation-id": "xxx",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "x-request-id": "xxx",
    "x-forwarded-for": "2.35.93.203",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "via": "1.1 vegur",
    "connect-time": "1",
    "x-request-start": "xxx",
    "total-route-time": "0",
    "content-length": "0"
  },
  "functionName": "getListOfItems"
}
```

the log of user inside the Cloud code function:

```
undefined
```

If I go back to version 1.12 I have no problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Is a iOs 10 simulator bug.
https://openradar.appspot.com/27844971